# Need Stored Procedure to import only selected data from .xls file to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Please see the screenshot - I want to import only columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K into a SQL Server table using a stored procedure. Bulk insert will not work in this case.

[image]

Comment: You may want to look into OPENROWSET ...  I tend to import data into a generic staging table for validation and final structuring.

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service. Furthermore, there are many discussions and suggestions for importing rows from a speadsheet which you can find by searching the internet. Try do a little research first - and perhaps reconsider this approach generally as such actions are not well suited to a pure tsql implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS you can write a query from an Excel connection like this:

```
Select * from [bisma$:B10:L]
```

And then just map into your destination.